# all elements in array before user input

Tags: powershell

I have a script that asks the user for input. Only five values are possible but I'd like to somehow compare his input to my hardcoded array and get all the elements before it.

```
$checkArray = @("one","two","three","four","five")
```

His input for example will be "three", then I want the array to become:

```
$array = @("one","two","three")
```

EDIT:
So far what I have:

```
$userinput = "three"
$checkArray = @("one","two","three","four","five")
$position = $checkArray.IndexOf($userinput)
$length = $checkArray.Length
$newarray = $checkArray | Select -First $($length-$position)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you tried so far. Take a look at [ask] and try to offer an [mcve] of your problem and your code.

Comment: I've added what I  have so far, sorry :)

Comment: Your code appears to work, what is the problem exactly?

Comment: It doesn't work as it should if the user input is "four", my new array becomes "one, two" instead of "one, two, three, four". If the user input is "two", I get "one, two, three, four" instead of "one, two".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need the length of the array, only the position. Add +1 to the position (arrays start counting at 0) and everything should work.

```
$userinput = "four"
$checkArray = @("one","two","three","four","five")
$position = $checkArray.IndexOf($userinput)
$newarray = $checkArray | Select -First ($position + 1)
$newarray
```